# Randomly change x amount of values to y in a z size array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-random

New to python and was wondering if the above could be done using python and numpy. I have an array of let's say size 10, I want to change 6 random values from their current value to something else I set. Is there a way to do this in numpy?

Comment: Yes, did you try anything so far?

Comment: _Is there a way to do this in numpy?_ Yes, what have you tried, and what research have you done?

Answer (score 0):

python's random module provides a method sample. By taking a random sample of the indices of your array you have a list of what to replace...

```
import numpy as np
import random

def randomReplace(arr,n,newValue):
    indicies = random.sample(range(0,len(arr)),n)
    for k in indicies:
        arr[k] = newValue

arr = np.random.rand(10)
print(arr)
arr2 = randomReplace(arr,6,1)
print(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

For example you have numpy array `arr` with size z, you want randomly change x values into y, you can try this one:

```
index = np.random.choice(z, x, replace=False)
arr[index] = y
```

Reference for random choice: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html#numpy.random.choice